# Unity - RegisterFactory vs RegisterInstance

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm new to Unity Containers but have some experience with IoC/DI, and whilst wiring a `ServiceClientFactory` I ended up with 2 ways to register a singleton for it:

```
// register factory singleton
var factory = new ServiceClientFactory(strategy);
container.RegisterInstance<IServiceClientFactory>(factory, InstanceLifetime.Singleton);

// register factory factory for the singleton
container.RegisterFactory<IServiceClientFactory>((x) => new ServiceClientFactory(strategy), FactoryLifetime.Singleton);
```

I've tested both versions with unit tests and both validate and work as expected, I'm not evaluating speed yet, so I suspect `RegisterFactory` may work under the hood differently.

When should one use one or the other? Is there a significant overhead by using `RegisterFactory`?

Which would be recommended for this case? `strategy` is just a local function that resolves factory expected types from the `IUnityContainer`.

I'd like to keep the factory container agnostic if we decide to go with another IoC library, or eventually use `IServiceCollection` too.

Comment: I suspect they both have the same end result and then it becomes a matter of preference. I'd do the former (its shorter), but I don't see anything that suggests that they're different.